# How to write string data to tiff file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to write some data which is string to tiff file. I am doing in the following way

```
Dim OFile As System.IO.File
Dim OWrite As system.IO.TextWriter
OWrite = OFile.CreateText("Signature.tiff")
OWrite.Write(ControlData)
MessageBox.Show("Signature is recieved and it is saved in Signature.tiff")
```

ControlData is the string which is to be written to the file.
I am capturing the signature from the user. This function gets the data in string format and i need to create a tiff file using the string data.

When i did in this way, signature.tiff is created but when i opened the image it is giving no preview available.

Can you tell me what is the problem or correct way of doing this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim format As StringFormat = New StringFormat()

Dim MyRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 400)
Dim MyGraphics As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
Dim MyImg As Image = New Bitmap(MyRect.Width, MyRect.Height, MyGraphics)
Dim imageGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(MyImg)
imageGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, MyRect)

format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
imageGraphics.DrawString("Hello Everyone", objFont, Brushes.Black, RectangleF.op_Implicit(MyRect))

MyGraphics.DrawImage(MyImg, MyRect)

MyImg.Save(filename)
```

Just see this may help you all for converting text string to image.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TIFF files are binary image files. You are writing the string to a text file. Try opening the file in Notepad to check.

You need a way to create an image in memory and save it to TIFF format.

You could use a PictureBox control. [Write the string onto the PictureBox](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=8669) then [save as a TIFF](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_change_image_type.html).

Comment: Hello Mark, Thanks for your reply I have looked at the link but it just went above my head. Is there any simpler way to do this? Instead of tiff when i used jpg file format, it gave same error. Can you help me out of this?
The problem in simpler words: Data is there in string format, i have to store and display as image.
Can you show me some direction to go for this?
Thanks.